# JPA Null Pointer Exception when adding to a list of entities to an entity that have @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following problem. I'm using Wildfly 11 as my Java EE server. I have a Customer entity that have a list of Address entities. I get a **NullPointerException** when I try to set the list of addresses to my customer.

My Address entity:

```
@Entity
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

private String street;
private String houseNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private Customer customer;
-- constructor, getters, setters --
```

My Customer can have multiple addresses:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
private List<Address> adresses;
-- constructor, getters, setters --
```

I also have a startup bean that tries to create the address and a customer add the address to the customer address list and persist the customer.

Here is how it looks like:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init () {
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setStreet("Example Street");
        address.setHouseNumber("123");

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Bob");
        customer.getAdresses().add(address);
        address.setCustomer(customer);

        em.persist(customer);
    }
```

Now, when I try to deploy my project to Wildfly 11, I get a NullPointerException at this line: `customer.getAdresses().add(address);`

Here's the full stack trace: 
01:00:26,529 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool

```
-- 210) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."my_project-ear.ear"."my_project-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".component.StartupBean.START: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."my_project-ear.ear"."my_project-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".component.StartupBean.START: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.getComponentInstance(SingletonComponent.java:124)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.start(SingletonComponent.java:138)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:54)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:188)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:354)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(LifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionContextInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.StartupCountDownInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupCountDownInterceptor.java:25)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.test.businesslogic.StartupBean.init(StartupBean.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:107)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Hello Jacques Blanc, welcome to StackOverflow. If you could post a complete stacktrace it would be very helpful. Also, I'd recommend stating your problem in the first few lines of your question (and then repeating it at the end, like you've already done)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your sugesstions. I will edit the question and add the stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a null pointer exception because the List of Addresses that you are trying to add to doesn't exist. You have to initialize it first. And also, List is an interface in Java. You need to instantiate an implementation of the List interface.

So, instead of `address.setCustomer(customer);` you should have:

```
    List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    addresses.add(address);
    customer.setAdresses(addresses);
```

And, another thing. This way you won't get your *Address* entry persisted. You would just have the *Customer*. And you won't get any exception because the FOREIGN_KEY is on the *Address* side the way you mapped your entities (tour @JoinColumn annotation is on the Address side of the relation).

In order to get both entities persisted successfully, you need to persist them both like this.

```
em.persist(address);
em.persist(customer);
```

The order in which you persist isn't important, because you use Java EE, and the Application Server takes care of transactions, so it won't actually commit the transaction until the end of your code, however I think it's more logical to persist the entities in this order.

You can avoid `em.persist(address);` by using the `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` property on @OneToMany annotation on your address list.

So, it would be: `@OneToMany(mappedBy="customer",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)`

This way when you persist the *Customer*, the *Address* is persisted too.